# DP_jQuery_* is not defined when using with google chrome extension at content level

Tags: jquery, dialog, datepicker, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a google chrome extension.
I am trying to use the jquery-ui datepicker inside a jquery-ui dialog of the existing webpage (content level)

Like so: [Screenshot](http://sites.google.com/site/kamimark/files/datepickerbug.JPG)

I get "DP_jQuery_1274168529407 is not defined" when I click on any button of the datepicker widget and I think that it's because jquery datepicker adds on the html:

```
onclick="DP_jQuery_1274192751418.datepicker._selectDay('#new\\-app\\-date',4,2010, this);return false;"
```

This means i'll have to change the datepicker library to avoid modifying the html but rather attach an event on each obj like this:

```
.click(function(){DP_jQuery_1274192751418.datepicker._selectDay('#new\\-app\\-date',4,2010, this);return false;})
```

This will probably keep the scope safe

What do you think?

Comment: I assume you are using script injection to get the library and plugin into the page? If not you might have context issues.

Comment: yeap something like this:

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["*"],
      "css": ["jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css", "background.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.4.2.js", "jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.js", "jquery-ui-content.hack.js", "content.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],

Answer (score 3):

My haxorz skills have once again prevailed!

Modifying code of jquery-ui.js in function _updateDatepicker at line 8307 by inserting:

```
.find('[onclick]').each(function(){
    var command = $(this).attr('onclick')+'';
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
    command = command.replace("function onclick(event) {","");
    command = command.substr(0, command.length-2);
    $(this).click(function(){eval(command);});
})
.end()
```

Will solve this problem.

I know it's ugly
I know it can be done with fewer lines
But it's just temporary until the jquery ui team fixes this

Comment: I've applied your method to line 8784 of jquery-ui-1.8.10.js, which lets the injected datepicker work, but the console is showing this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement