# Add a Date Picker to a textbox using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, datepicker, greasemonkey

There is a textbox that requires a date but has no date picker.  I would like to add one with Greasemonkey.  I looked for an example but could not find one.

Is this possible?  Is there an example for doing this? It doesn't need to be fancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use [jQuery UI's datepicker()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) because I usually have jQuery UI loaded anyway, and it's fairly well-known/supported.

Unfortunately, the datepicker functionality uses some criminally-bad event code, which requires a little fudging to work in a sandboxed environment.

Still, its not too difficult.  Here is a complete Greasemonkey script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Datepicker fun
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include     http://jsbin.com/ukelij*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js
// @resource    jqUI_CSS  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Date picker needs additional CSS
GM_addStyle (GM_getResourceText ("jqUI_CSS") );

//--- Add datepicker popups to select inputs:
$("#pickMe").datepicker ();
$("#pickMe").click ( function () {
    setTimeout (cleanUpCrappyEventHandling, 100);
} );

/*--- Clean up ultra-crappy event handling ('til dev team eventually fixes).
    This must be done to allow the picker to work in a sandboxed environment.
    Alternately, you can modify the jQuery-UI source ala http://stackoverflow.com/q/2855403
*/
function cleanUpCrappyEventHandling () {
    var nodesWithBadEvents  = $(
        "div.ui-datepicker td[onclick^='DP'], div.ui-datepicker a[onclick^='DP']"
    );
    nodesWithBadEvents.each ( function () {
        var jThis       = $(this);
        var fubarFunc   = jThis.attr ("onclick");

        /*--- fubarFunc will typically be like:
            DP_jQuery_1325718069430.datepicker._selectDay('#pickMe',0,2012, this);return false;
        */
        fubarFunc       = fubarFunc.replace (/return\s+\w+;/i, "");

        jThis.removeAttr ("onclick");
        jThis.click ( function () {
            eval (fubarFunc);
            cleanUpCrappyEventHandling ();
        } );
    } );
}
```

You can load this and test it against [this page at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ukelij/2).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this awesome code but it's not working for me.  Running the JavaScript console I see this error "GM_getResourceText is not defined"

Comment: You are using Firefox and Greasemonkey, right?  Are you trying to run this code directly in the console?  `GM_getResourceText` will work only inside a FF, GM script or when using *Tampermonkey* if running Chrome.