# jQuery not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

This code was provided to me in another question I asked but I am getting errors right at the start.  Here is the part of the code causing the problem:

```
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js
// @resource    jqUI_CSS http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
// ==/UserScript==

var cssResource = GM_getResourceText("jqUI_CSS");
GM_addStyle(cssResource);

$("#pickMe").datepicker();
```

The first error I get is "GM_getResourceText is not defined"

If I comment out that, and the next line, then the next error I get is
"uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined." And I get that on the last line.

It's like the script is not getting the jQuery stuff from Google.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You have to include jQuery _someplace_... without it, you will get errors.

Comment: And you should really keep your follow-up confined to [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734525/add-a-date-picker-to-a-textbox-using-greasemonkey) to reduce reader confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, "Userscripts" are extensions. The easiest way to use external libraries is by configuring the code through a [manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html).

Download [`jquery.min.js`](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js), [`jquery-ui.min.js`](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js) and [`jquery-ui.css`](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css), and place them in the same directory. **Make sure that you resolve the paths of the images** (CSS), by replacing all occurrences of `url(...)` with `url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/...)`.

Create a `manifest.json` file, and add the following content:

```
{
    "name": "Name of your extension.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [
               "jquery.min.js",
               "jquery-ui.min.js",
               "mycode.js"
              ],
        "css": [ "jquery-ui.css" ],
        "matches": [ "http://similarto-at-include-in-greasemonkey.com/*" ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

Create a file called `mycode.js` (or any desired name), and add the following content:

```
$("#pickMe").datepicker();
```

You can load or pack your extension via `chrome://extensions/`, developer mode.

Comment: Rob, this looks great but I get an error "Could not load extension from '[blah]'. Manifest is not valid JSON.  Line: 7, column: 16, Syntax error." That line is "mycode.js".  And I am trying to load it with no changes to your manifest.json code.

Comment: I have updated my answer, a comma was missing at line `"css": ...`.

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks.  There is also one missing after "jquery-ui.min.js".

Comment: what's the matches thing ?