# jQuery DatePicker is not changing month/year when used inside a userscript

Tags: jquery, datepicker, userscripts

I figured out how to show the month and year dropdown boxes but nothing happens when I select them. Basically if you select a new month/year it should change to that new month/year.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but here is what I've got so far:

```
$("input[name=myDate]").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'
);
```

The alert isn't even firing.  Any help is appreciated.

***Update:***

I've added below the code someone gave me that I need to use in order to make the date selection fire.  If I don't use this code then when I select a day it doesn't go into the text box.  Maybe this is affecting the month/year selection?

```
$("input[name=myDate]").click(function () {
    setTimeout(cleanUpCrappyEventHandling, 100);
});

function cleanUpCrappyEventHandling() {
    var nodesWithBadEvents = $(
        "div.ui-datepicker td[onclick^='DP'], div.ui-datepicker a[onclick^='DP']"
    );
    nodesWithBadEvents.each(function () {
        var jThis = $(this);
        var fubarFunc = jThis.attr("onclick");

        /*--- fubarFunc will typically be like:
        DP_jQuery_1325718069430.datepicker._selectDay('#pickMe',0,2012, this);return false;
        */
        fubarFunc = fubarFunc.replace(/return\s+\w+;/i, "");

        jThis.removeAttr("onclick");
        jThis.click(function () {
            eval(fubarFunc);
            cleanUpCrappyEventHandling();
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the alert is firing here: http://jsfiddle.net/zmtAD/

Comment: Is this still inside your Chrome userscript?  That is a key bit of information in this case; remember the event handling woes, discussed [in this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8735550/).

Comment: Also, what does the error console say?  Does it have exceptions like `DP_jQuery_1325878693641 is not defined`?

Comment: Brock, yes, this is inside my Chrome userscript/extension.  Yes, it does have an exception like that in the error console.  I've tried the code like scott has below but still no event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the month and year in the calendar happens automatically in the date picker, you don't need code to do that for you:

```
$("input[name=myDate]").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'
    }
);
```

Also, I'm not sure I understand what is happening in your `onChangeMonthYear` event.  According to the current documentation, `month` and `year` are not options.  And even if they are, you are setting them to true, not the new values.

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/g6EXh/

Comment: Also, the alerts fired for me, in jsfiddle.

Comment: In fact, the alert fires twice, once with the new month & year and once with the old month & year.  I guess onChangeMonthYear fires twice, but I don't know why.

Comment: Scott, you example on that site is working for me too.  It's just not working as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in a userscript/extension environment, you need to extend `cleanUpCrappyEventHandling()` to account for the dropdown boxes.  (My code for your other question did not include such because (1) I don't use that functionality and (2), Trying to keep the example from getting too complicated unless there's a known demand for it.)

Anyway, replace `cleanUpCrappyEventHandling()` with the following and the drop-downs should work also. :

```
function cleanUpCrappyEventHandling () {
    //-- Fix base controls.
    var nodesWithBadEvents  = $(
        "div.ui-datepicker td[onclick^='DP'], div.ui-datepicker a[onclick^='DP']"
    );
    nodesWithBadEvents.each ( function () {
        fixNodeEvents ($(this), "click");
    } );

    //-- Fix month and year drop-downs.
    nodesWithBadEvents  = $(
        "div.ui-datepicker select[onchange^='DP']"
    );
    nodesWithBadEvents.each ( function () {
        fixNodeEvents ($(this), "change");
    } );
}

function fixNodeEvents (jNode, eventType) {
    var onName      = "on" + eventType;
    var fubarFunc   = jNode.attr (onName);

    /*--- fubarFunc will typically be like:
        DP_jQuery_1325718069430.datepicker._selectDay('#pickMe',0,2012, this);return false;
    */
    fubarFunc       = fubarFunc.replace (/return\s+\w+;/i, "");

    jNode.removeAttr (onName);
    jNode.bind (eventType, function () {
        eval (fubarFunc);
        cleanUpCrappyEventHandling ();
    } );
}
```

---

Note that the userscript/extension environment is markedly different from normal, page-context JS.  This is why the other answer works in a normal page but not in a userscript.  Please write and tag questions with this in mind.